# unable to forward X11 applications

Tags: ssh, sshd

I installed a headless Debian server which has Wireshark installed. Now I would like to run Wireshark in a way that it uses X11 server running in my Linux Mint laptop. As a first step I permitted X11 forwarding in Debian SSH server configuration file:

```
root@A58:~# grep X11Forwarding /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
X11Forwarding yes
root@A58:~#
```

Then I restarted SSH server with `/etc/init.d/ssh restart` and finally executed SSH client in my laptop using `-X` which enabled X11 forwarding. However, I still receive the "cannot open display" error:

```
root@A58:~# echo "$DISPLAY"
localhost:11.0
root@A58:~# wireshark 

(wireshark:3590): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: localhost:11.0
root@A58:~# time xterm
Warning: This program is an suid-root program or is being run by the root user.
The full text of the error or warning message cannot be safely formatted
in this environment. You may get a more descriptive message by running the
program as a non-root user or by removing the suid bit on the executable.
xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: %s

real    1m3.131s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
root@A58:~#
```

Is the "$DISPLAY" variable correct? At the moment it's pointing to Debian server.. If the "$DISPLAY" variable is correct, then it's probably an authorization issue with X11 server?

X11 in laptop is started in following manner:

```
root      1113  0.1  4.3 101396 89992 tty7     Rs+   2013  44:28 /usr/bin/X :0 -nr -verbose -auth /var/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-FHVC1j/database -nolisten tcp vt7
```

Comment: You might be missing the xauth program, do you have it installed on your server?

Comment: @Cristian Măgherușan-Stanciu At first I thought that I need to allow access to X11 server with `xhost`, but I guess that this is actually not needed as I'm tunneling over SSH? `xauth` program needs to be installed and configured in X11 server, i.e. my laptop running Linux Mint?

Comment: @Martin I also think you'll need the `xauth` program, on the server. You might need to install some `X` libraries for that, even though your server is meant to be headless. As far as I remember, that's just the way it is, but I could be wrong.